# Merging XPathResults from document.evaluate

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, document.evaluate

I'm doing a bunch of document.evaluate then iterating through each result with a for loop on `result.snapshotLength`.

Since I do the same thing inside each loop (a `thisDiv.parentNode.removeChild`) I would like to do just one loop.

I've read that :

> The fifth parameter can be used to
>   merge the results of two XPath
>   queries. Pass in the result of a
>   previous call to document.evaluate,
>   and it will return the combined
>   results of both queries

So I tried :

```
comDivs = document.evaluate(
    "//div[@class='class name 1']",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);

ggDivs = document.evaluate(
    "//div[@class='class name 2']",
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    comDivs);
```

But this doesn't work (although I don't have an error log, it just doesn't work).

What's the proper way of doing that? Can I run different XPath queries and merge the results? Or is there a way to pass regular expressions or some kind of alternation to the query itself?

The code I have for now is at : http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/58939

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `I've read that : The fifth parameter can be used to merge the results of two XPath queries.` Yup, that’s certainly [supposed to be the case](http://help.dottoro.com/ljruhkuj.php). Unfortunately, finding an example usage is proving difficult. `But this doesn't work (although i don't have an error log, it just doesn't work).` What exactly happened? Did the results object contain only the first set? Only the second set? Was it empty? (Obviously the question is dead, but I ask for future readers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your XPath in the userscript and join single expressions with "`|`":

```
"//div[@class='reactionsCom reactionsNiv1 first'] | " + 
"//div[@class='googleBanner'] | " + 
"//div[@class='blocE1B-16b'] | " +
"//div[@class='blocE1B-16b clear']"
```

or even better in one expression with severel conditions:

```
"//div[@class='reactionsCom reactionsNiv1 first' or " +
      "@class='googleBanner' or " +
      "@class='blocE1B-16b' or " +
      "@class='blocE1B-16b clear']"
```

As for your example above, iirc the second query would only find matches, if the result f the first query contained them, i.e. if `//div[@class='class name 2']` where children of the result nodes from the first query `//div[@class='class name 2']`.

Comment: thanks a lot that's pretty cool !
the syntax doesn't strike me as super clear, with the or statement inside the double quotes ;)

Comment: That's just the string split on multiple lines for readablity (i thought :-O), if you want, you can do the whole expression in one string.

Comment: I tried the second method (combined-condition), but it just wouldn’t work in a Chrome extension (one condition would always fail to return regardless of whether I put it first or second). Using the first method with separate expressions worked perfectly. Thanks! (Though I’d still be interested in finding out if there’s a way to merge multiple `XPathResults` since I’ve read that while they behave a lot like arrays, they are not technically arrays and don’t include a lot of standard array functionality, so the obvious ways wouldn’t work.)